# Get free time slots of an employee during scheduling in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a set of employees and a set of time slots. For example

```
Employees

EMP1
EMP2
EMP3
EMP4
EMP5  

Time Slots

08:00AM-10:00AM
10:00AM-12:00PM
04:00PM-06:00PM
08:00AM-12:00PM
02:00PM-06:00PM
08:00AM-04:00PM
09:00AM-01:00PM
08:30AM-01:30PM
12:00PM-04:00PM
 2:00PM-3:00PM
```

An employee can be allocated to any timeslots. What I need is that, if an Employee is allocated in time slots 8:00Am-12:00PM then that Employee should not be available in 08:00AM-10:00AM and  10:00AM-12:00PM slots. Similarly, if  an employee is allocated in 04:00PM-06:00PM then that employee should not be available in any of the timeslots between 04:00PM-06:00PM, but can be available before and after time slots, not in between.

How to do this?

Comment: Do you need help with the DB schema? Or with the query that gets the data?

Comment: Please post the actual database type (SQL Server? Oracle) and also post what you've tried so far.

Comment: You have a _terrible_ question history. Unclosed questions. Duplicate questions. It's quite obvious that you will either not return to this question or will simply not understand that answer

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: @AbdullahDibas I need the query that gets the data

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid SQL SERVER

Comment: If you know that actual version of SQL Server, please edit your question and add the appropriate tag.

Comment: If all you want is a query, we need to know how the data is stored. How are the employees and timeslots linked? What does the table(s) look like? Can you have more than one employee in a given timeslot?

Comment: In the first place how does an employee gets allocated a time slot ? Any criteria ? rule ? logic ? constraints ?

Comment: @Squirrel Employees can be allocated in any time slot at first .I want to show a list of non allocated time slots in a grid with stored procedure.For example ,I have allocated EMP1 in timeslot (08:00AM-12:00PM) then agian in the non allocated list ,this employee should not be available in time slots between (08:00AM-12:00PM) and EMP 1 should be available only in timeslots  04:00PM-06:00PM,02:00PM-06:00PM,12:00PM-04:00PM
 2:00PM-3:00PM.

Comment: can you please post your table DDL with sample data with exepcted result ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select shift times based on a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51496252/select-shift-times-based-on-a-condition)

Answer (score -1):

I assume you have a bridge table that maps Employees and timeslots. I could develop a solution by the below schema i developed

```
SELECT * INTO dbo.Employees FROM (
SELECT 1 empid,'EMP1' emp
union
SELECT 2,'EMP2'
UNION
SELECT 3,'EMP3'
UNION
SELECT 4,'EMP4'
UNION
SELECT 5,'EMP5' )a

SELECT * INTO dbo.TimeSlots FROM (
SELECT 1 sltid,'08:00AM-10:00AM' slt
UNION
SELECT 2,'10:00AM-12:00PM'
UNION
SELECT 3,'04:00PM-06:00PM'
UNION
SELECT 4,'08:00AM-12:00PM'
UNION
SELECT 5,'02:00PM-06:00PM'
UNION
SELECT 6,'08:00AM-04:00PM'
UNION
SELECT 7,'09:00AM-01:00PM'
UNION
SELECT 8,'08:30AM-01:30PM'
UNION
SELECT 9,'12:00PM-04:00PM'
UNION
SELECT 10,'2:00PM-3:00PM')a


SELECT * INTO dbo.TimeSlotsemp FROM (
SELECT 1 emp,2 slt
UNION
SELECT 1,3
UNION 
SELECT 2,6)a

--available slots
SELECT DISTINCT a.empid,a.emp,d.slt AS availableslots FROM employees a
cross JOIN timeslots d
LEFT JOIN TimeSlotsemp b ON a.empid = b.emp
left JOIN timeslots c
ON b.slt = c.sltid
WHERE (d.sltid NOT IN (SELECT slt FROM timeslotsemp WHERE emp = a.empid) or a.empid NOT IN (SELECT emp FROM timeslotsemp))
```